# ACL: givin - - - permissions for the owner fo the file

Tags: files, permissions, acl

At the beginning, I have these permissions for a file:

```
# file: jar
# owner: my_user
# group: my_user
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::r--
```

After running this:

```
setfacl -m u:my_user:--- jar
```

and get this permissións:

```
# file: foobar
# owner: my_user
# group: my_user
user::rw-
user:my_user:---
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

I expected `my_user` not to have permissión to read (for example) this file, but it has..

Answer (score 1):

Try the next command:

```
setfacl -m u::--- jar
```

With that commando you apply to the owner.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect that?

From the [`man setfacl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setfacl.1.html) man page:

> The setfacl utility recognizes the following ACL entry formats (blanks inserted for clarity):
>
> `[d[efault]:] [u[ser]:]uid [:perms]`
>   
>  Permissions of a named user. Permissions of the file owner if uid is empty.
>
> `[d[efault]:] g[roup]:gid [:perms]`
>   
>  Permissions of a named group. Permissions of the owning group if gid is empty.
>
> `[d[efault]:] m[ask][:] [:perms]`
>   
>  Effective rights mask
>
> `[d[efault]:] o[ther][:] [:perms]`
>   
>  Permissions of others.

ACLs are separate from the traditional Unix access controls -- owner, group, and the rights mask for owner, group, and others.

While we cannot think of any reason why you'd need an ACL with the same user or group as the traditional access controls, it is not in the Unix philosophy to decide that it should be therefore forbidden. `setfacl` happily allows you to do that; [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_Principle) is good.

If you don't like that behaviour, and would prefer the utility to "autodetect" that situation, you can write your own wrapper around `setfacl`. In a shell script, you can use `stat -c %U FILE` to obtain the name of the owner, and `stat -c %G FILE` the name of the group of file or directory `FILE`. In organizations with complex sets of users and groups such wrappers -- not just for `setfacl`, but for all file ownership management -- are ubiquitous in my experience.